# Make two conditions and it returns a column with its result in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formula

[image]I need to create a new column that meets the following conditions. in pandas

this is my current dataframe

```
Ruote   B   C   D        E
R1    115   1   150     -35
R2    155   1   150     5
R3   155    6   150     5
```

New column named F

```
Ruote   B   C   D    E   F
R1     115  1   150 -35  0
R2     155  1   150  5   1
R3     155  6   150  5   5
```

Example of the conditions that column F must satisfy

```
IF   “E” <= 0 , Put  0
IF “C “<= “E” Put “C “on the contrary Put  “E”
```

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.   **DO NOT** post links to code, or data, - copy or type the text into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of your Excel formula is:

```
import numpy as np

np.where(df['E'].lt(0), 0, np.minimum(df['C'], df['E']))
```

Or, easier, if your goal is to have the minimum of C/E but never below 0:

```
df['F'] = np.minimum(df['C'], df['E']).clip(lower=0)
```

Output:

```
  Ruote    B  C    D   E  F
0    R1  115  1  150 -35  0
1    R2  155  1  150   5  1
2    R3  155  6  150   5  5
```